# WSO2 IS 5.0 SP1 : User/Role management in Multitenancy

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

Env: WSO2 Is 5.0 SP1

I have created two tenants and have separate secondary store configured in each on of it. Is there a way where I can share the role among them? i.e can I create the role in Primary store and would they be accessible in tenants?
I don't see much documentation around multi-tenancy in wso2 Is 5.0 sp1. Any pointers would be helpful

Regards,
Cijoy

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share primary roles(created by super admin) with tenants with the wso2 identity server `5.0 or 5.1`.

Because there is no data sharing across multiple tenants in WSO2 products. Each tenant is isolated from others & They have different users/roles.Even supper tenant cannot be share data with other tenents

This improvement already included in Identity server roadmap and this will be release in future.

Comment: But in the UI I can see something called share role if i enable it via user-mgmt.xml. What is it then?